# Create class instances like Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I was looking at some [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests) code for some new ideas for my framework, and I found they declare their class instances like:

```
Request $request;
```

Which then acts as a `Request` class reference, I also noticed that there's a namespace being added in the Laravel code.

I looked all around the `PHP Manual`, re-read the `OOP Manual` as well as re-read the `namespace` section as well, some code I've tried:

```
// Includes a class called PSM
PSM $psm;
$psm->version();
```

I understand that'd be under "alternate syntax" structure, and also couldn't find anything under that name either.

I realized this was similar to `C# Syntax`, whereas when declaring variables or class instances, you give them a specific data-type which with instances is their own class-name. (**Might be the wrong definition, the main thing to take from that was the C# similarities of this syntax**)

As it might be confusing, I'm talking about the creation of the `$request` instance from simply typing:

```
Request $request;
```

Which then brings the class instance into the scope of the Controller.

Comment: Look at [dependency injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about [IoC](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container). You can bind any class using Laravel container and then use this syntax to resolve this class:

```
function index(Request $request)
```

> The Laravel service container is a powerful tool for managing class dependencies and performing dependency injection. Dependency injection is a fancy phrase that essentially means this: class dependencies are "injected" into the class via the constructor or, in some cases, "setter" methods.

Comment: I understand that; what I'm curious about is how `Request $request` is related with PHP's base syntax to let that work. :-)

Comment: @jek I think it's not base php syntax! Laravel just pars it and  translates it before run!

Comment: @Jek google for `dependency injection` and `type hint php`. I guess [this](http://php-di.org/doc/best-practices.html) will be helpful reading.